# How can I detect what app is being run on my iPhone from an app I'm building on Swift for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to build an app `MyApp` that helps me with other apps. To do this, I'm making a list of apps (Instagram, Facebook, Chrome and a few others), so that when I'm actively viewing those apps on the list, `MyApp` can run some functions in the app - mostly stat monitors of what I do in each of those apps.

Is there any way to do this on Swift? In other words, can I get system data and process it in an app running in the background?

Comment: It would be a privacy issue if one application could track your activity in / usage of another application, especially if those apps weren't developed by the same company.

Comment: no you can't... as stated above it would be a serious privacy issue so Apple wouldn't allow it. Each app runs in its own sand boxed environment and doesnt have access to system level information and other apps

Comment: Hmmm so sad. That's ok - thanks for the answer.